# Why do some Debian packages recommend unavailable dependencies?

Tags: debian, apt

By checking the [`dkms`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/dkms) package dependency, I noticed that `apt` may recommend to install some packages which are not packaged by Debian. In the following example there are such two packages. It is clear that `apt` will ignore them during the installation:

> ```
> rec: linux-headers-686-pae
>     Header files for Linux 686-pae configuration (meta-package) 
> or linux-headers-amd64
>     Header files for Linux amd64 configuration (meta-package) 
> or linux-headers-generic
>     Package not available 
> or linux-headers
>     Package not available
> ```

Why do some Debian packages declare unavailable dependencies in their control files (`Recommends` field)?

Comment: Contrast: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/dkms It's probably so that the maintainer can use the same control file for both Debian and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/569576/why-some-debian-packages-recommend-unavailabe-dependency#comment1059292_569576) by [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru), this is probably to simplify the maintenance of the `dkms` package [in Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dkms). [The commit introducing this](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/dkms/-/commit/eff2f3e9e1eabdc653c55126ba0241377b9ffcbf) doesn’t mention any reason for adding `linux-headers-generic`, so we have to guess, but it’s not all that unusual for Ubuntu-specific support to be included in Debian packages (see [this example](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/solaar/-/commit/60b5233d7a30eea9a5129f7e01a30d5dd849b99c#8756c63497c8dc39f7773438edf53b220c773f67_0_30) in one of my packages).

Optional dependencies on packages which aren’t available in Debian can seem surprising, but they’re not forbidden. [Debian Policy constrains strict dependencies](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive.html#archive-areas) but not weak dependencies, and some packages in Debian recommend or suggest packages which aren’t available in *any* repository (because they are produced from proprietary data using other packages).